# How can I replace the contents of a link with CSS?

Tags: css

Is there any way to replace a link's content using CSS only? I do not want to hide the link, only to replace the text in it, e.g. changing `<a href="">text</a>` to `<a href="">bla bla</a>`.

I know of after and before, but I still need the link, so I can't hide the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Make the color transparent?

Comment: `display: none`? What exactly do you wanna do?

Comment: or `visibility: hidden` ?

Comment: You should put that into your question.  The previous version of your question (before you edited it) was actually far better in explaining what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `font-size:0` then reset it on a pseudo-element.

```css
a {
    font-size:0;
}

a:before {
    content:"new text";
    font-size:1rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="">text</a>
```

Note that some broswer (perhaps older Chrome) won't let you reduce font-size below certain values [4px?] (IIRC)

Comment: this works!! Thanks a lot! So simple but great! ahaha

Comment: That was classic Opera (v12 and below); it wouldn't use a font size of 0 if the user had set a minimum size.

Answer (score 1):

```
.mylink {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.mylink:before {
  content: "My New Content";
  visibility: visible;
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydrcaenj/1/).

Comment: @tarleb can you create a fiddle demonstrating how `display: none` would work with `:before`?  I tried using `display: none` first but was unable to make it work properly.

Comment: Don't know what I was thinking.  You are right, of course.